# How to make the subprocess statment to execute under the os.walk(path)

Tags: python

I want my script to go under a particular file path mentioned in `os.walk()` and then execute a `grep` command on all the files under that location and redirect the output to a file. Below is the script I created, but the `subprocess` executes `ls -al` command under the current directory but the `print` statment show me the contents of `os.walk`. So I need the `subprocess` to execute the command under the `os.walk` path as well.

```
  with open('ipaddressifle.out', 'w') as outfile:
     for pdir, dir, files in os.walk(r'/Users/skandasa/perforce/projects/releases/portal-7651'):
         for items in files:
             print(items)
             #subprocess.call(['ls', '-al'])
         process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-al'], shell= True, stdout=outfile, stderr=outfile)
         #process = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'PORTALSHARED','*', '|', 'awk', '-F', '[','{print', '$1}'], shell= True, stdout=outfile, stderr=outfile)
         [output, err] = process.communicate()
```

And is there anyother way apart from adding a `cd` command to the `subprocess` call.

Comment: [subprocess.Popen() documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen): `If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed.`

Comment: I tried it didn’t seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the current working directory.

I reworked your snippet to use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to call a command and retrieve its stdout. I also use [`shlex.split(command)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to write the command in a single string and split it correctly for `Popen`.

The script does `os.walk(DIRECTORY)` and write the output of `ls -la` in each subdirectory into `OUTPUT_FILE`:

```
import os
import shlex
from subprocess import check_output


DIRECTORY = '/tmp'
OUTPUT_FILE = '/tmp/output.log'


with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as output:
    for parent, _, _ in os.walk(DIRECTORY):
        os.chdir(parent)
        output.write(check_output(shlex.split('ls -al')))
```